spring-aop-6.1.1-upgrading java from 11 to 17
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAdviceParameterNameDiscoverer$AmbiguousBindingException: Found 2 potential annotation variable(s) and 2 potential argument slots
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAdviceParameterNameDiscoverer.bindAnnotationsFromVarNames(AspectJAdviceParameterNameDiscoverer.java:431) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAdviceParameterNameDiscoverer.maybeBindAnnotationsFromPointcutExpression(AspectJAdviceParameterNameDiscoverer.java:420) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAdviceParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(AspectJAdviceParameterNameDiscoverer.java:252) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.core.PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.java:55) ~[spring-core-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.bindArgumentsByName(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:434) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.calculateArgumentBindings(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:389) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.getAdvice(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:303) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.InstantiationModelAwarePointcutAdvisorImpl.instantiateAdvice(InstantiationModelAwarePointcutAdvisorImpl.java:152) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.InstantiationModelAwarePointcutAdvisorImpl.<init>(InstantiationModelAwarePointcutAdvisorImpl.java:116) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]

facing this issue while updating java from 11 to 17 and try to up service locally

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please learn how to ask a question on SO and provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Or can you debug invisible code? Thank you.
